# debian download where

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, iso-image

where can I find all Debian release iso images with Linux kernel `2.4.x`?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifically looking for Woody or Sarge as per the [kernel list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Kernels). Then compare that to the [debian page](http://www.debian.org/releases/), which states that the obsolete releases arn't included is the regular mirror and only select [archives](http://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) you should be able to find what you're looking for from there...Eventually...

Course, you could ask google, which would take you to an ArsTechnica discussion of exactly the same thing that gives [this](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/images/) link for the iso files.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite and old kernel. As far as I remember most, if not all the [Debian worldwide mirror sites](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list) have all the distros available, including the older versions.

Check the dists folder and maybe the oldstable folder too.

Comment: well it's hard to find ISO image in those site.

Answer (score 0):

Check at [archive.debian.net](http://archive.debian.net/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=kernel-image) - looks like they called it kernel-image back then. Now it's linux-image package.